# How can I ajust this Query about Convert Datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to convert this YYYY/MM/DD for French/English format for two columns.

Should look like this: 09/11/2021 - DD/MM/YYYY

This is how my boss send me:

```sql
where convert(datetime,H6_DATAINI) >= '${_from:date:iso}'  AND
      convert(datetime,H6_DATAFIN) <= '${_to:date:iso}'
```

```
H6_DATAINI    H6_DATAFIN
20211005      20211005
...           ...
...           ...
...           ...
...           ...
...           ...
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Why change the format at all? Why not use a date and time data type? fix your design and then you don't have to do any of this. Formatting is the job of the presentation layer, not the SQL layer.

Comment: `${_from:date:iso}` I hope this doesn't mean you are injecting data into your query. You should use proper parameterization